# How to register dockable panel programmatically in revit api c#

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I am working on a project that requires me to launch a plugin in a dockable panel, 
I followed the example [here](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/05/a-simpler-dockable-panel-sample.html). I could achieve this, but I was wondering if the registering process can be done programmatically.

If anyone has achieved this, can you please guide me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
[Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
[Regeneration(RegenerationOption.Manual)]
public class App : IExternalApplication
{
    public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application)
    {
        RegisterDockPanel(application)
        return Result.Succeeded;
    }

    public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication application)
    {
        return Result.Succeeded;
    }

    private void RegisterDockPanel(UIControlledApplication app)
    {
        //DockPage as System.Windows.Control.Page implements Autodesk.Revit.UI.IDockablePaneProvider interface;
        DockPage dockPage = new DockPage();
        DockablePaneId dpid = new DockablePaneId(new Guid("---your guid---"));            
        app.RegisterDockablePane(dpid, "DockPanel Name", dockPage as IDockablePaneProvider);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out[The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) topic group on [dockable panels](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.4). Yes, I am pretty sure you can automate the whole process.